# Determine VBIOS of Nvidia GPU

Tags: nvidia, graphics, bios

I have a laptop with 2 GPUs (integrated one and an NVIDIA one). I would like to know what is the VBIOS of my NVIDIA graphics card. It is classified as a 3D controller

```
lspci -vnn | grep 3D -A 12
```

[image]

and

```
lshw -numeric -C display
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open Nvidia X Server Settings and click on your adapter.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Another, if not easier, approach would be to use the nvidia-smi utility.  Both nvidia-settings and nvidia-smi use the same underlying API to communicate with the GPU.

- nvidia-smi is a CLI application, and has a more portable, smaller footprint on disk
- nvidia-smi can be used remotely (over ssh), or within any console session (i.e. when X won't start)
- nvidia-smi can be parsed programmatically (so you could, as an example, write a script in bash or python to determine your VBIOS version)

You can find the nvidia-smi utility in the Ubuntu provided package nvidia-utils, which as of the time of this writing (with the latest release of the nvidia-kernel-open drivers version r515) is named nvidia-utils-515

Here is an example:

```
user@host:$ dpkg-query -W 'nvidia-utils-*'
nvidia-utils-515    515.43.04-0ubuntu1

user@hots:$ dpkg -L nvidia-utils-515 | grep "nvidia-smi"
/usr/bin/nvidia-smi
/usr/share/doc/nvidia-utils-515/nvidia-smi.html
/usr/share/man/man1/nvidia-smi.1.gz

user@host:$ nvidia-smi -q | grep "VBIOS"
    VBIOS Version                         : 94.02.32.00.02
    VBIOS Version                         : 94.02.4B.00.0B
```